# mysql convert date from mm-dd-yyyy to YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to convert  given date  from **`mm-dd-yyyy`** to **`YYYY-MM-DD format`**

I have tried following

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("09-02-2018",'YYYYMMDD')

SELECT DATE_FORMAT("09-02-2018", "%MM %dd %YY");

SELECT CURDATE("09-02-2018");

SELECT DATE_FORMAT("09-02-2018", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

It works fine for current date, but not for a given date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use STR_TO_DATE function to convert your string date to date type. For example:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("09-02-2018", '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. From MySQL documentation:

> It takes a string str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE()
>   returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and
>   time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date
>   or time parts. If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str
>   is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning.
>
> The server scans str attempting to match format to it. The format
>   string can contain literal characters and format specifiers beginning
>   with %. Literal characters in format must match literally in str.
>   Format specifiers in format must match a date or time part in str.

- `%m` represents Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
- `%d` represents Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- `%Y` represents Year as a numeric, 4-digit value

Since your input date is in `mm-dd-yyyy` format, we use `%m-%d-%Y` as the format here. Check the following code:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('09-02-2018', '%m-%d-%Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

The original format is not the MySQL format, so DATE_FORMAT won't work

You should do something like

```
SET @toconvert = '09-02-2018';
SELECT
    CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(@toconvert,7,4),'-',SUBSTR(@toconvert,4,2),'-',SUBSTR(@toconvert,1,2)) AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax to get date in format.

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(myVal, '%d.%m.%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

use STR_TO_DATE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/71892

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("09-02-2018", '%d-%m-%Y')
```